# Magento Share cart with multi website

Tags: magento

I have bellow structure of stores and website

```
Website 1
   |
    Store 1

Website 2
   |
    Store 2

Website 3
   |
    Store 3
```

Now each store has 10 -10 different products . So total 30 products.

Now when some one add store 1 product on cart, than it should be on all website.

I want to do something like that.

Please help me to solve this issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Dharmesh Hariyani,
I have done  `this type of task on Magento C.E  1.6` 
Using below blog of hussy

http://husseycoding.blogspot.in/2011/09/magento-sharing-cart-between-stores.html